# when Fourier transform function in $\mathbb C$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis

The Fourier transform of a function $f\in\mathscr L^1(\mathbb R)$ is

$$\widehat f\colon\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb C, x\mapsto\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\exp(-ixt)\,\textrm{d}t$$

When is this indeed a function in $\mathbb C$? Most of calculations you get functions in $\mathbb R$. When  in $\mathbb C$?

Add: I know there are results like $\frac{e^{ait}-e^ {-ait}}{2i}=\sin(at)$ multiplied by 'anything', but I am asking for a function which you cannot write as a function in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Only even (symmetric) functions have real Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that is not symmetric, such as

$$f(t) = \begin{cases} \\ e^{-t} & t>0 \\ 0 & t< 0 \end{cases}$$

whose FT is

$$\hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{1+i x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another example: if $\mathcal{F}[f(t)]=\widehat{f}(\omega)$ is real, then $\mathcal{F}[f'(t)]=i\omega\widehat{f}(\omega)$ is purely imaginary and $\mathcal{F}[f(t)+f'(t)]=(1+i\omega)\widehat{f}(\omega)$ is truly complex.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic fact about Fourier transform on the Schwartz space: Let $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\widehat{f'} = it\widehat{f}$. Thus, if $\widehat{f}$ is real-valued, then $\widehat{f'}$ is complex-valued.